# Segfault on Qt signal emission

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, signals

I have the following function which segfaults upon emission. Knowing only the following, what are some conditions that could cause this segfault?

**Function**

```
MyClass::EmitSignal() {
    QString param = SomeObject->GetHelloWorld();
    qDebug () << "param: " << param;
    emit SomeSignal (param);
    qDebug () << "Emitted SomeSignal";
}
```

**Signal prototype**

```
signals:
    void SomeSignal (const QString& someString);
```

**Output**

```
param: HelloWorld
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Show the slot which receives the signal.

Comment: "*Knowing only the following...*"  That's an unusual way to present your problem.  You don't want to show any more?

Comment: You surely have run the code in the debugger, have you?

Comment: @Roku, I'm working under strange circumstances which unfortunately preclude the use of a debugger.

Comment: Just for the heck of it, have you tried changing the signal prototype to `void SomeSignal (QString);`

Comment: Have you checked that the instance of MyClass is not null or some uninitialized garbage?

Comment: Don't use references in parameters with signals unless you KNOW the reference will remain good for all slots that need it. Even then, it's prone to errors if you change code later and forget. This is generally NOT safe to do.

Comment: You should use a debugger to get a hint where it happens.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid mistake on my part--someone else connected to my signal over the weekend and their code segfaulted when the I changed the format of the QString. I should have checked for new slots.

Answer (score -1):

if SomeObject is equal to null or invalid you get a segfault for sure

Comment: That is not the case here since he gets "HelloWorld" from it.